# Error in selecting value from RavenDB

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I am using RavenDB in my mvc4 project when store an object of class to RavenDB it works fine but when performing select operation it throws an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on all queries

**RavenbaseController.cs**

```
public class RavenBaseController : Controller
{
   public IDocumentSession RavenSession { get; protected set; }

   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      RavenSession = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession("ravendbtesting");
   }

   protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
      if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
         return;

      using (RavenSession)
      {
         if (filterContext.Exception != null)
             return;

         if (RavenSession != null)
             RavenSession.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

**Activation.cs**

```
public class Activation : RavenBaseController
{
    public string tokenid { get; set; }

    public bool validate(string tid)
    {
        var query = from u in RavenSession.Query<Register>() where u.TokenId == tid select u;

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            v.IsApproved = true;
        }

        RavenSession.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Queries** tried:

```
var results = from u in RavenSession.Query<Register>()
    where u.TokenId == tid
    select u;

var query= RavenSession.Query<Register>()
                                     .Where(x => x.TokenId == tid)
                                      .ToList();
```

I can't understand why it is not working  i am new to RavenDB

**Update**

All the queries work fine if run from controller but if run from class file, the error "Object reference not set to  an instance of an object" occurs

Comment: what do you mean by *"run from class file"*? Is `RavenSession` instantiated properly?

Comment: `RAVENSESSION` is properly instantiated
but if i run the query from class in Model folder then i didnt work
but if run from `Controller` then it work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you try to instanciate `var ctrl = new Activation();` and do `ctrl.validate(x);` it won't work as `OnActionExecuting` didn't run. That function is called automatically by the MVC framework when serving a request, not when manually testing.

Since MVC instantiates a new controller on each requests anyway, you should move the RavenSession initialization to the constructor since you do not seem to use any info in the request context:

```
public class RavenBaseController : Controller
{
   public IDocumentSession RavenSession { get; protected set; }

   public RavenBaseController()
   {
      RavenSession = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession("ravendbtesting");
   }

   protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
      if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
         return;

      using (RavenSession)
      {
         if (filterContext.Exception != null)
             return;

         if (RavenSession != null)
             RavenSession.SaveChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

The even better way is to use Dependency Injection to pass the session as a constructor parameter, but the above should work for you.